# How to play audio with looping a specific part of a file?

Tags: jquery, audio

```
<audio id='a01'><source src="music.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
```

js

```
$(".stars").click(function() {
    $('#a01')[0].play();
});
```

This works but how can I say something like this:

```
   $(".stars").click(function() {
var selector=$('#a01')[0];      
selector.currentTime = 10;
selector.finalTime = 20;
selector.attr.add('loop');  
selector.play();  // play with loop from 10 to 20 sec.

});
```

Comment: see http://buzz.jaysalvat.com/ i think it will helpful for you  :)